# Spark achieve parallel Cross Validation for Scala api

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml

Pyspark offers a great possibility to parallelize cross-validation of models via https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn
as simple substitution of sklearn's `GridSearchCV` with

```
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
```

How can I achieve similar functionality for Spark's Scala `CrossValidator` i.e. to parallelize each fold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Since spark 2.3 :**

**You can do that using the `setParallelism(n)` method with the `CrossValidator` or on creation**. i.e :

```
cv.setParallelism(2)
```

or

```
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=evaluator, \ 
                    parallelism=2)  // Evaluate up to 2 parameter settings in parallel
```

**Before spark 2.3 :**

***You can't do that in Spark Scala. You can't parallelize Cross Validation in Scala Spark.***

If you have read the documentation of `spark-sklearn` well, GridSearchCV is parallelized but the model training isn't. Thus this is kind of useless on scale. Furthermore, you can parallelize Cross Validation for the Spark Scala API due to the famous `SPARK-5063` :

> RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

**Excerpt from the [README.md](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn/blob/master/README.md) :**

> This package contains some tools to integrate the Spark computing framework with the popular scikit-learn machine library. Among other tools:
>
> train and evaluate multiple scikit-learn models in parallel. It is a distributed analog to the multicore implementation included by default in scikit-learn.
>   convert Spark's Dataframes seamlessly into numpy ndarrays or sparse matrices.
>   (experimental) distribute Scipy's sparse matrices as a dataset of sparse vectors.
>   It focuses on problems that have a small amount of data and that can be run in parallel.
>
> for small datasets, it distributes the search for estimator parameters (GridSearchCV in scikit-learn), using Spark,
>   for datasets that do not fit in memory, we recommend using the distributed implementation in Spark MLlib.
>
> **NOTE: This package distributes simple tasks like grid-search cross-validation. It does not distribute individual learning algorithms (unlike Spark MLlib).**

Comment: You mean different sets of parameters are evaluated in parallel, each set uses cross-validation sequentially? So far `CrossValidator ` only seemed to test parameter combinations sequentially. How could parallelism be enabled there?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Parallelism can be enabled just on one level : model selection or model training and not both.

Comment: The default spark `CrossValidator ` will work with `ML` to distribute the models but not the parameter selection. Would it be possible to switch to such a similar mode?

Comment: I don't get your last question.

Comment: databricks skelarn-spark package allows training different parameter combinations in parallel. How can I achieve similar things in sparks native scala API? The default `CrossValidator` seems to be serial.

Comment: You can't do that in Scala @GeorgHeiler

Comment: Why not? What about asynchronous spark jobs started from a single driver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132399/discussion-between-eliasah-and-georg-heiler).

Comment: the latest version of spark has some support for this feature.